# ISSUE facing to post feed on twitter

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

please help me i m stucked here

I am integrating  twitter in my app using twitter engine api ,i have integrated it successfully and getting the time line too.

But during the feed post i m getting the following error..

Request DEFC2D14-F4A6-4508-A990-ED4219FC2C5C failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=401  "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)

I am not being able to understand what is wrong i m doing, any idea?

thanks in advance..

Comment: which framework are u using, twitter in ios 5 or twitter engine?

Comment: When you post duplicate feed within short time you will get this error too. So please confirm that if you do so ?

Comment: I am using twitter engine ...

Comment: thanks @Jennis but i m not posting the duplicate feed its giving me at first time ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. i used this and this doesnt give any errors. i hope it helps u as well...

```
 self.tweetView = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
TWTweetComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler completionHandler=^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) 
{
};
[tweetView setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:tweetURL.text];//in case u need to post a URL

[tweetView setInitialText:textView.text]; //custom text in the tweet
[tweetView addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Twitter-icon-3.png"]]; //add image to post
[tweetView addURL:url];
[self presentModalViewController:tweetView animated:YES];
```